# lsblk not listing USB stick

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-drive, partitioning, format

I already crashed a USB stick couple of month ago, this time it's a little more expensive, so I would like to repair it (last time I removed it without having savely removed, this time I have no idea why it's defect).

My two Kubuntu systems do not react to the usb stick, my two windows systems can't detect it correctly neither (nor repair it consequently).
It's neither shown in gparted nor in lsblk.
Sometimes lsusb recognizes it:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05dc:a838 Lexar Media, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x05dc Lexar Media, Inc.
  idProduct          0xa838 
  bcdDevice           11.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

I can recognize it via dmesg:

```
[   77.676004] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   77.809438] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05dc, idProduct=a838
[   77.809446] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   77.809450] usb 3-3: Product: USB Flash Drive
[   77.809454] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Lexar
[   77.809457] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: AADBL26RWXBD0NG2
[   77.826299] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   77.826443] scsi host5: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[   77.826562] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   77.829127] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  100.256875] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  105.368403] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  120.583302] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  120.799303] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  120.911288] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  121.127280] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  121.343233] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  121.343320] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  121.547266] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  121.751155] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[  121.863174] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  121.863316] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  122.067232] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  122.271085] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[  122.271211] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  122.383077] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  122.495086] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  122.711142] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  122.927043] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  123.039102] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  123.255217] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  123.471041] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  123.471218] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  123.675183] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  123.879044] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[  123.991010] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  123.991154] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  124.195085] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  124.398957] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[  124.398989] usb usb3-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

PS: I don't really need the data, would be nice for others anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the USB drive is not recognized as a mass storage device (which might be the problem according to the description in your question), analyze the problem according to this link,

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

It is worthwhile to try the tips in this list

> - Reboot the computer and try again to restore or wipe the first megabyte with mkusb.
> - Disconnect other USB devices. Sometimes USB devices can disturb the function for each other.
> - Try other USB ports and another computer.
> - Try another operating system (Windows, MacOS) in another computer.
> - There is a limit, when you have
>     to accept that the pendrive is damaged beyond repair, at least with
>     tools available to normal users like you and me. See this link:
>     [Pendrive lifetime](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)

Comment: Does not work for me since neither lsblk (Link) nor mkusb does list the device.

Comment: What about the tips in the list? Reboot, Disconnect other USB devices, Try other USB ports, Try another computer, Try another operating system. -- If still no luck, I am afraid that your USB drive is damaged beyond repair.

Comment: I tried two Windows 10 systems and two Kubuntu systems... BTW: I updated my question, sometimes lsusb lists the device. Sometimes differently (Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan) I bought it this year, didn't use it too much.

Comment: So you have already tried with another computer or operating system. The USB drive might be failing electronically or maybe there is a mechanical damage to a connecting strip inside the plug of  the USB drive. -- What happens, when lsusb sees the drive: Will mkusb see it too?

Comment: No, mkusb does not show the stick, even if lsusb does.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have not much hope for that stick. It cannot do what is necessary for the operating system to recognize it as a mass storage device (a drive for storing data). *Maybe* it would be possible, if you could get the program code, that was used at the factory, where the internal system of the USB stick was made. But it could also be a hardware fault, and then I don't think you can do anything to fix it, (except if you can see that one of the connector strips is offset, and you can get it lined up correctly).

Comment: Still had warranty & got a new one! :)

Comment: I'm glad you got a new stick :-) See this link about pendrive lifetime: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297 -- When old pendrives get slower (typically reduce the writing speed to half), I wipe the whole device with mkusb. It recovers almost the original write speed by relieving the internal management of the memory cells (connecting logical cells with physical cells by releasing cells that have been written to seldom because they have been storing data). The risk for gridlocking is also reduced. But don't do it too often, because of the wear of cells.